I want to be able to compile ZipAlign for Windows from its source code
I would like to be able to compile ZipAlign for Windows, need to make few small changes and compile it. It can be downloaded for Windows (zipalign.exe) so it should be possible to compile it for this platform. I have found a source code here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/main/tools/zipalign/
It also uses some framework libraries like VectorImpl
I haven't worked with Android tool sources before.
Can someone give me some advice how I can accomplish this task?

From what I recall the AOSP is pretty monolithic and builds the Windows binaries from Linux, see: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt and https://github.com/anatol/android-platform-tools-build/blob/master/README.md so the easiest path may be to find a fork/port in github and use that as a starting point.

And don't expect to find a simple way to just compile the tool you need. The AOSP and Android SDK tools are usually embedded into a large build system. I assume that is what Morrison calls "monolithic".
